# Tell LaTeX not to indent the next paragraph after my command

Tags: indentation

When using LaTeX for note-taking, I like to separate topics with a horizontal line. However, I'd prefer it if the first paragraph after the line wasn't indented, similarly to the start of a new section.

The following achieves the horizontal line, but the next paragraph is still indented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\rulebreak}{\vspace{1em}\noindent\hrulefill\vspace{1em}\noindent}

\begin{document}

\section*{A Section}

This is the first paragraph in a new section - it isn't indended.

\rulebreak

This is the first paragraph after a rulebreak - it shouldn't be indented.

The second paragraph should be indented as usual.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried adding `\ignorespaces` at the end of the definition of `\rulebreak`, but it had no effect. (I guess it only ignores spaces, not line breaks?)

How can I prevent the paragraph after the rule from being indented?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rulebreak}{%
\par\vspace{1em}\noindent\hrulefill\par\vspace{1em}%
\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

Note I've added a few `\par` such that the macro does not depend on the user having blank lines above and below. It is the `\@afterheading` macro that does the trick, this is what `\section` and friends use.

Comment: May I know the function for the tag `\@afterindentfalse`? Please

Comment: @MadyYuvi it is just setting the boolean `\if@afterintent` to `\iffalse` and latex tests for this at various points to suppress indentation (by removing the indent box, not by using `\noindnent`)

Comment: I've noticed a very strange problem with this: if I replace `\section*` in my MWE with `\paragraph` then the paragraph after the rule gets indented after all. Do you have any idea why that would happen or how to prevent it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just to make sure I'm being clear, the issue seems to be that if the last section heading happened to be a `\section` then the `\rulebreak` command works as intended, but if the last section heading was a `\paragraph` then it doesn't, even if there are some other paragraphs in between the `\paragraph` and the `\rulebreak`.

Comment: @N.Virgo try now (and see MadyYui's hint about the missing flag-)

Comment: @MadyYuvi ^^^^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle great, thank you! I'd tried replacing `\@aftersection` with `\@afterindentfalse` but hadn't thought of trying both.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot for the best clarification.